# References to descriptions of the formless realms in the suttas (or other Theravada texts)

Tags: reference-request, realms

For example in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_cosmology_of_the_Theravada_school#Arupa-Loka_(Formless_Realms)) it mentions: "The inhabitants of these realms are possessed entirely of mind". Also, "They do not interact with the rest of the universe".

In "In the Buddha's Words" (Bhikkhu Bodhi) it mentions "The lifespans ascribed to these realms are
respectively 20,000; 40,000; 60,000; and 84,000 great eons".

I'm looking for that kind of descriptions of the formless realms but in the suttas (or other source Theravada texts).

Answer (score 3):

> ...They enjoy it and like it and find it satisfying. If they’re set on that, committed to it, and meditate on it often without losing it, when they die they’re reborn in the company of the gods of the dimension of infinite space. The lifespan of the gods of infinite space is twenty thousand eons.

> ...If they’re set on that, committed to it, and meditate on it often without losing it, when they die they’re reborn in the company of the gods of the dimension of infinite consciousness. The lifespan of the gods of infinite consciousness is forty thousand eons.

> ...The lifespan of the gods of nothingness is sixty thousand eons. ~~ [AN 3.116](https://suttacentral.net/an3.116/en/sujato) ~~